# How to configure the Router in the Micro-Frontends Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, micro-frontend

I am working on a UI application using *Micro-Frontend architecture*. The micro-frontend app has its router to manage the routing, and it is working as expected as a standalone application. When used in combination with the host application, routing does not work correctly. Is there a way to set up routing by separating it from the host application?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? In principle, the host app controls the routing because once the remotes are federated in, they really become part of the shell app. So usually you want to try to prevent depending on routing in remotes.

Comment: Thanks for your message. When I run the application as remote, the URL differs from the standalone execution due to the presence of an extra path. As a result, routing stops working because the mapped paths no longer match.